# Problem establishing relationship on existing nodes on Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm getting a "no changes, no records" message whenever I try to establish a relationship between 2 separate nodes that I have created.

```
Create(Redmayne:actor{name: "Edward Redmayne", PlaceOfBirth: "England", YearOfBirth: 1982})
return Redmayne;
```

2nd node

```
Create(`Fantastic Beasts`:movie{language:"English", genre:"Family"})
return `Fantastic Beasts`;
```

Relationship query

```
Match (a:actor), (b:movie)
where a.name="Edward Redmayne" and b.name="Fantastic Beasts"
Create (a)-[r:`acted in`]->(b)
return a,b;
```

Any clue as to what am I doing wrong?

Comment: You never created a `name` property for your movie node, so your `match` is failing (well, the `where` is failing, since you never set the movie node's `name` property).

Comment: Also - not that it's causing you issues but... I'd refrain from using node variables with spaces in them.

Comment: @DavidMakogon makes sense.... thank you